# Files aren't rendering on website (connected to Amazon EC2 file directory using Filezilla SFTP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp, amazon-ec2, filezilla

I registered a virtual domain with namecheap and set up an Amazon EC2 instance (I also set up an elastic IP, it looks like I did this correctly).

I was able to have the EC2 instance successfully point to my virtual domain. I used Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server for this.

I am using Filezilla to transfer via SFTP, I can successfully SSH into filezilla and upload files to the server successfully as well. However, the files don't render on the actual website when I visit the URL.

I checked out some tutorials and think I set up my security groups correctly. I don't see a public_html folder to upload files though, and this seems pretty ubiquitous as a standard directory. When I visit my domain I just see the default apache index.html file.

Any ideas would be appreciated, I leaned a lot on this tutorial when setting things up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qxs7CYguo70

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading your files into the correct folder?

I upload my files to /var/www/html using filezilla and that works

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Filezilla to transfer via SFTP, I can successfully SSH into filezilla and upload files to the server successfully as well. However, the files don't render on the actual website when I visit the URL.

It's not enough to just dump files anywhere on the server. The location where you need to upload the files is the location that *you configured* in Apache – that's the `DocumentRoot` option inside whatever <VirtualHost> you added. A fresh Apache installation will have one "default" vhost that's configured to use either `/srv/http` or `/var/www(/html)`, usually.

---

> I don't see a public_html folder to upload files though, and this seems pretty ubiquitous as a standard directory.

No – although usage of `public_html` for each domain's files is pretty common *on shared hosting systems*, which have been pre-configured in a certain way by the server admins, but it is not actually the default configuration on "fresh" Apache web servers.

(The original purpose of `public_html` is actually for "tilde" [user directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html), where each user could get their own "~subdirectory" under the system's main domain. The shared hosting systems obviously drew inspiration from that, adapted for the "personal domain" model.)